# My mvc action can't update the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update my model using MVC so i write this code to do that :

```
    SemesterRepositor obj = new SemesterRepositor();


  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        return View(obj.FindSemesterById(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id,FormCollection collection)
    {

        var review = obj.FindSemesterById(id);
        if (TryUpdateModel(review))
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(review);
    }
```

One of this method get the model and another one that is for post back updates the model .but it doesn't work .Why?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to send data from a view back to the controller.  The easiest way is to tie your model items on the view to for helpers (except display) and then do a post back.  your input on the post method would need to include the model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SemesterRepositor sr){
    //save the data in sr to your database
    RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

you have form collection as an input to your post method which will have fields from your view but to save the values you would have to pass the individual fields to your database.  In your code you have find semester by id but you don't ever set the form collection values to that object so it will always be empty

Update:

if your view has @model SemesterRepositor at the top and you use for helpers on your view your fields will be tied to the model

```
@model SemesterRepositor
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
```

something like this.  Then on post back the field Name will have the value of the text box tied to it

Comment: So how can i set form collection ?

Comment: see my update above.  The form collection will have values from your form.  Fields with a name on them if memory serves.  You will have to parse through it to see what was returned and grab the fields from it individually to use them.